# Python, delete a list item from class method

Tags: python, list, magic-methods

I have  my class.
I want to create a method inside to delete a list item by code attribute.

```
class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, code, name):
        self.__code = code
        self.__name = name
    @property
    def code(self):
        return self.__code
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
    @code.setter
    def code(self, new_code):
        self.__code=new_code
    def __repr__(self):
        x = f"Code: {self.__code} and Name:{self.__name}"
        return(x)
    def __deleteitem__(self, code):
        print("The code: {self.__code} was deleted")

list=[]
list.append(MyClass(1234,"Aijio"))
list.append(MyClass(123,"Anodnd"))
list.append(MyClass(1236,"Jfifi"))
list.append(MyClass(1238,"Roberto"))

print(list)

lista.deleteitem(123)
```

How I can create a method who deletes the code that I send?

Regards

Comment: I wonder if [this description](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4i63ba/what_is_the_difference_between_del_delete_and/) helps a bit?

Comment: Delete the code from where - from the list? Why would that method needs to be in the class, when you're deleting from the list? Try something like this:
`list = [item for item in list if item.code != 123]`

Comment: There is no `__deleteitem__` special method. Did you mean `__delitem__` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below :

```
class MyClass(Base):
        def __init__(self, code, name):
            self.__code = code
            self.__name = name
        @property
        def code(self):
            return self.__code
        @property
        def name(self):
            return self.__name
        @code.setter
        def code(self, new_code):
            self.__code=new_code
        def __repr__(self):
            x = f"Code: {self.__code} and Name:{self.__name}"
            return(x)
        def __deleteitem__(self, code):

            # Logic for deletion

            for obj in list:
                if obj.code == code:
                    list.remove(obj)
            print("The code: "+code+" was deleted")

    list=[]
    list.append(MyClass(1234,"Aijio"))
    list.append(MyClass(123,"Anodnd"))
    list.append(MyClass(1236,"Jfifi"))
    list.append(MyClass(1238,"Roberto"))
    myclass = MyClass(None, None)
    myclass.__deleteitem__(123)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, how you can call that method?

Comment: You need to make a dummy object of your class.I have edited my answer.

Comment: This code has several serious problems. The list to delete from being hardcoded (!!) is only one of them.